# Failed to generate Android incremental OTA package

Tags: android, linux, android-source

Getting error while trying to generate incremental OTA using the following command -
./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files -i PREVIOUS-msm8953_64-target_files-eng.root.zip NEW-msm8953_64-target_files-eng.root.zip incremental_ota_update.zip
after generating target files.

```
unzipping target target-files...
(using device-specific extensions from target_files)
unzipping source target-files...
loaded device-specific extensions from /tmp/targetfiles-WAy71u/META/releasetools.py
using prebuilt boot.img from IMAGES...
using prebuilt boot.img from IMAGES...
using prebuilt recovery.img from IMAGES...
Total of 786432 4096-byte output blocks in 27 input chunks.
Total of 786432 4096-byte output blocks in 27 input chunks.
Finding transfers...
Generating digraph...
Finding vertex sequence...
Reversing backward edges...
  0/0 dependencies (0.00%) were violated; 0 source blocks stashed.
Improving vertex order...
Revising stash size...
  Total 0 blocks (0 bytes) are packed as new blocks due to insufficient cache size.
Reticulating splines...
      4096       4096 (100.00%)     new __COPY 0
Computing patches (using 12 threads)...
 [100%] __NONZERO-6

ERROR:
Failed to generate imgdiff for //system/app/G4qolsys/G4qolsys.apk: tgt=314217-318509, src=314217-318509:
W/ziparchive(29582): Zip: bad offsets (dir 17461248, size 122968, eocd 17580120)
imgdiff E 03-03 22:00:40 29582 29582 imgdiff.cpp:661] Failed to open zip file /tmp/src-qiUV7M: Invalid offset
```

Comment: Check whether the target zip is corrupted.

Comment: checked the target files zip, it is ok.

Comment: Check whether /system/app/G4qolsys/G4qolsys.apk is corrupted

Comment: @Yong Thanks for the reply. How to check if the apk is corrupted?

Comment: apk is a zip too.

Comment: Checked if /system/app/G4qolsys/G4qolsys.apk is corrupted, but it is ok.

Comment: It seems that there is a issue in ziparchive. You can modify the loginc in build/make/tools/releasetools/blockimgdiff.py to use blockdiff, not imgdiff for G4qolsys.apk. The logic is in CanUseImgdiff

Answer (score 0):

It could be issue when  .so file directly integrated in to apk not exported to use the Android.mk reference.
Please check in apk does it includes any .so files .